# AngularJS Where should i set or store the configuration for a modul

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i've made an reusable module for angularJS. The module is manipulating templates inside the `run` function.  Before its gets fully initialized i need to set various properties. In which function should i expose this properties ?

Answer (score 1):

In my Angular-1.2 apps to configure the `ngRoute`'s service I use a `config` block like this

```
app.config(function ($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider....
});
```

I think you could do the same by adding a service provider into your module.

Another solution would be to make your `run` block depend on a `constant` that would be defined from your application.

```
// In your module
foo.run(function (fooConfig) {
  var url = fooConfig.url;
  ...
});

// In your app
app.constant('fooConfig', { url: ... });
```

Both solutions are demoed here : http://jsfiddle.net/JQ4Gm/

Answer (score 0):

I should expose my "properties" inside a provider and access them inside config. [Usage of provider](https://gist.github.com/Mithrandir0x/3639232).